# Create table with year and week number in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I m using postgresql 8.2.
I want to be able to create a simple table with year and all the week number upto 52 for that year.
Like this:

There must be an efficient way to do this.
If it needs to scale out to any year, it should dynamically list all the week number for year.

Any help is appreciated.
TIA

[image]

Comment: Do you need a table? You'd usually use [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-srf.html) to build these sorts of things on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, PostgreSQL does not have a function that returns the number of weeks a year. So I guess the best way to proceed is to create this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weeks_in_year(aYear integer) RETURNS integer AS
$$
DECLARE
  vW integer;
BEGIN
  vW := date_part('week', (aYear::text || '-12-31')::date);
  -- When the week is the first, the year has 52 weeks.
  RETURN CASE WHEN vW = 1 THEN 52 ELSE vW END;
END  
$$
  language 'plpgsql';
```

Then you can use this function with generate_series to get your data

```
select 2013 AS year,generate_series(1, weeks_in_year(2013)) AS week
```

if you have to create a table, you can use

```
SELECT 2013 AS year,generate_series(1, weeks_in_year(2013)) AS week INTO my_table
```